# Get data by comparing two dates in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Im getting travel details week by week and going to calculate working hours he spent in client place.Below I have an employee who travelled outside from 03Apr2016 to 30th Apr 2016.Available record for that month for that employee is only one.

```
43  3   International   Moho    Nether  2016-04-03 14:29:12 2016-04-30 14:29:12 Demo
```

Just I want to retrieve records by week by week. So I tried one query, it returns row for certain dates and sometimes doesn’t.
Just I tried these three queries with the dates of the week.

```
//Last week of april (25th Apr to 1st May)
SELECT * FROM simhrmdb.employeetravelrecords where employee = 3 and (date(travel_date) >= '2016-04-25' and date(return_date) <= '2016-05-01');    //0 row(s) returned
SELECT * FROM simhrmdb.employeetravelrecords where employee = 3 and (date(travel_date) <= '2016-04-25' or '2016-05-01' <=  date(return_date));   //1 row(s) returned
SELECT * FROM simhrmdb.employeetravelrecords where employee = 3 and ((date(travel_date) >= '2016-04-25' and date(travel_date) <= '2016-05-01' ) or (date(return_date) >= '2016-04-25' and date(return_date) <= '2016-05-01'));  //1 row(s) returned

//Fourth week  (18th Apr to 24th Apr)
SELECT * FROM simhrmdb.employeetravelrecords where employee = 3 and (date(travel_date) >= '2016-04-18' and date(return_date) <= '2016-04-24');  //0 row(s) returned
SELECT * FROM simhrmdb.employeetravelrecords where employee = 3 and (date(travel_date) <= '2016-04-18' or '2016-04-24' <=  date(return_date));  //1 row(s) returned
SELECT * FROM simhrmdb.employeetravelrecords where employee = 3 and ((date(travel_date) >= '2016-04-18' and date(travel_date) <= '2016-04-24' ) or (date(return_date) >= '2016-04-18' and date(return_date) <= '2016-04-24'));   //0 row(s) returned

//Third week  (11th Apr to 17th Apr)
SELECT * FROM simhrmdb.employeetravelrecords where employee = 3 and (date(travel_date) >= '2016-04-11' and date(return_date) <= '2016-04-17');  //0 row(s) returned
SELECT * FROM simhrmdb.employeetravelrecords where employee = 3 and (date(travel_date) <= '2016-04-11' or '2016-04-17' <=  date(return_date));  //1 row(s) returned
SELECT * FROM simhrmdb.employeetravelrecords where employee = 3 and ((date(travel_date) >= '2016-04-11' and date(travel_date) <= '2016-04-17' ) or (date(return_date) >= '2016-04-11' and date(return_date) <= '2016-04-17'));  //0 row(s) returned

//Sec week  (4th Apr to 10th Apr)
SELECT * FROM simhrmdb.employeetravelrecords where employee = 3 and (date(travel_date) >= '2016-04-04' and date(return_date) <= '2016-04-10'); //0 row(s) returned
SELECT * FROM simhrmdb.employeetravelrecords where employee = 3 and (date(travel_date) <= '2016-04-04' or '2016-04-10' <=  date(return_date)); //1 row(s) returned
SELECT * FROM simhrmdb.employeetravelrecords where employee = 3 and ((date(travel_date) >= '2016-04-04' and date(travel_date) <= '2016-04-10' ) or (date(return_date) >= '2016-04-04' and date(return_date) <= '2016-04-10')); //0 row(s) returned

//Firs week  (28th Mar to 3rd   Apr)
SELECT * FROM simhrmdb.employeetravelrecords where employee = 3 and (date(travel_date) >= '2016-03-28' and date(return_date) <= '2016-04-03'); //1 row(s) returned
SELECT * FROM simhrmdb.employeetravelrecords where employee = 3 and (date(travel_date) <= '2016-03-28' or '2016-04-03' <=  date(return_date)); //1 row(s) returned
SELECT * FROM simhrmdb.employeetravelrecords where employee = 3 and ((date(travel_date) >= '2016-03-28' and date(travel_date) <= '2016-04-03' ) or (date(return_date) >= '2016-03-28' and date(return_date) <= '2016-04-03')); //1 row(s) returned
```

From the above testing, the second query is working in all conditions. But still when I use it in my PHP file, the 2nd query didn’t work for the date (25th Apr to 01st may ).

```
PHP coding:
///////////Employee Outstation(Travel) details/////////////
        $employeeTravel = new EmployeeTravelRecord();   
        $TravelEntryList = $employeeTravel->Find("employee = ? and (date(travel_date) <= ? and ? <=  date(return_date))",array($employeeId,$start,$end));
    //  $TravelEntryList = $employeeTravel->Find("employee = ? and ((travel_date >= ? and travel_date <= ? ) or (return_date >= ? and return_date <= ?))",array($employeeId,$start,$end,$start,$end));      
        $startdate = $start;
        $enddate = $end;
        $TravelTime = 0;
        foreach($TravelEntryList as $Travelentry){          
                $TraveldateArr = explode(" ",$Travelentry->travel_date);
                $Traveldate = $TraveldateArr[0];                
                $ReturndateArr = explode(" ",$Travelentry->return_date);
                $Returndate = $ReturndateArr[0];                
                if($startdate >= $Traveldate)
                {$firstdate = $startdate;
                }
                else
                    $firstdate = $Traveldate;

                if($enddate <= $Returndate )
                {
                    $lastdate = $enddate;
                }
                else
                    $lastdate = $Returndate;

                $holidays = $this->getholidays($firstdate,$lastdate);

                $totalhours = $this->getWorkingDays($firstdate,$lastdate,$holidays);                    
                $amount = $totalhours;
                error_log("totalhours" . $totalhours);
                $TravelTime += $amount;     
        }
```

I don’t know where is the mistake and in order to get week by week record, by having only two dates (travel and return date) which one is best?

I followed the third query for getting leaves taken by the employee week by week by having From and To date of leaves. 
But it works fine there. 
That’s why I chose it for travel records. But here 3rd query not working for all cases.

The same 2nd query returns 1 row for the week (09May - 15th may)

```
SELECT * FROM simhrmdb.employeetravelrecords where employee = 3 and (date(travel_date) <= '2016-05-09' and '2016-05-15' <=  date(return_date));
```

How can i avoid that??

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: i have to calculate required working hours vs actaul working hours. i will detect this travel time from total hours needed.i have to get data from travel databse for particular period.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `or` condition for validating your date columns in your SQL query (`... <= '2016-04-25' or '2016-05-01' <= ...`), but in PHP script your are using `AND` instead of the or clause (`... <= ? and ? <= ...`). Try to change the condition `<= ? **or** ? <=` (replace the `and` with `or`) and check the same.

```
TravelEntryList = $employeeTravel->Find("employee = ? 
and (date(travel_date) <= ? or ? <=  date(return_date))",array($employeeId,$start,$end));
```